# How to solve an equation that contains Sum in SymPy?

Tags: sympy

I want to solve the following equation for *x* with SymPy:

[image: formula]

(Note that the equation can be simplified as mentioned in the comments, I copied it verbatim from an example in a legal document.)

According to my understanding, this translates to the following SymPy expression:

```py
from sympy import Sum, solve
from sympy.abc import k, x

solve(350 - 18500 + Sum(182.94 * (1/(1+x)**(k/12)), (k, 1, 120)), x)
```

However, when I run this, the result is empty:

```
[]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you can bring `182.94` in front of the sigma symbol since it does not include `k`. Addition has the following feature: `ax + ay = a(x+y)`.

Comment: You are right, I followed the given example to the letter, without simplifying it. That should not affect SymPy calculation though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`solve` probably shouldn't give `[]` but you will get better results from `nsolve` for this expression using a guess for `x` near 0:

```
>>> from sympy.abc import k, x
>>> from sympy import nsolve
eq = 350 - 18500 + Sum(182.94 * (1/(1+x)**(k/12)), (k, 1, 120))
>>> nsolve(eq, 0)
0.0397546543274819
>>> eq.subs(x,_).round(2)
0
```