# How to solve an equation that contains sigma sum to find the upper limit of sigma in Python

Tags: python, sympy, solver, equation-solving

I want to find an integer value from a sigma contained equation with two variables like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61362303/13394817)

[image]

where `x` (a real decimal value) range is between two limits e.g. `known_xmin_value <= x < known_xmax_value`. `1` is the lower limit of `k` (which is the integer) but don't know the upper limit (which is the goal to be derived from the solution); Perhaps just could be guess that it will be lower than 2000000. Is it possible to find the integer for `k`? How?

```
from sympy import Sum, solve
from sympy.abc import k, x

known_value = 742.231       # just for example
known_xmin_value = 3.652    # just for example

solve(-known_value + Sum((x + (k - 1) * (x - known_xmin_value)) ** 3, (k, 1, integer_unknown_limit)), x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymPy can compute the sum symbolically:

```
from sympy import *

from sympy import Sum, solve
from sympy.abc import k, x, y

# Use exact rational numbers
known_value = Rational('742.231')       # just for example
known_xmin_value = Rational('3.652')    # just for example

sum_value = Sum((x + (k - 1) * (x - known_xmin_value)) ** 3, (k, 1, y))
```

This is the summation and its result computed using `doit`:

```
In [22]: sum_value
Out[22]: 
  y                           
 ____                         
 ╲                            
  ╲                          3
   ╲  ⎛            ⎛    913⎞⎞ 
   ╱  ⎜x + (k - 1)⋅⎜x - ───⎟⎟ 
  ╱   ⎝            ⎝    250⎠⎠ 
 ╱                            
 ‾‾‾‾                         
k = 1                         

In [23]: sum_value.doit()
Out[23]: 
                                       ⎛ 2    ⎞   ⎛      2                         ⎞ ⎛ 3    2    ⎞   ⎛ 4    3    2⎞ ⎛           2                        ⎞
761048497⋅y   ⎛2500707⋅x   2283145491⎞ ⎜y    y⎟   ⎜2739⋅x    2500707⋅x   2283145491⎟ ⎜y    y    y⎟   ⎜y    y    y ⎟ ⎜ 3   2739⋅x    2500707⋅x   761048497⎟
─────────── + ⎜───────── - ──────────⎟⋅⎜── + ─⎟ + ⎜─────── - ───────── + ──────────⎟⋅⎜── + ── + ─⎟ + ⎜── + ── + ──⎟⋅⎜x  - ─────── + ───────── - ─────────⎟
  15625000    ⎝  62500      15625000 ⎠ ⎝2    2⎠   ⎝  250       31250      15625000 ⎠ ⎝3    2    6⎠   ⎝4    2    4 ⎠ ⎝       250       62500      15625000⎠
```

This is a quartic polynomial in `y` so the equation can be solved explicitly in radicals giving 4 symbolic expressions for the roots:

```
In [24]: s1, s2, s3, s4 = solve(sum_value.doit() - known_value, y)

In [25]: print(s1)
(-250*x*sqrt(62500*x**2/(62500*x**2 - 456500*x + 833569) - 456500*x/(62500*x**2 - 456500*x + 833569) - 1000*sqrt(833569*x**2 + 185557750*x - 677656903)/(62500*x**2 - 456500*x + 833569) + 833569/(62500*x**2 - 456500*x + 833569)) - 250*x + 913*sqrt(62500*x**2/(62500*x**2 - 456500*x + 833569) - 456500*x/(62500*x**2 - 456500*x + 833569) - 1000*sqrt(833569*x**2 + 185557750*x - 677656903)/(62500*x**2 - 456500*x + 833569) + 833569/(62500*x**2 - 456500*x + 833569)) - 913)/(500*x - 1826)
```

For any particular value of `x` probably none of these 4 roots will be equal to an integer though.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for a numerical solution, a naive approach would be a brute force over a set of `integer_unknown_limit` and use numerical root finding algorithms. For example:

```py
from sympy import *
from scipy.optimize import root
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, k, integer_unknown_limit = symbols("x, k, u")
known_value = 742.231       # just for example
known_xmin_value = 3.652    # just for example
expr = -known_value + Sum((x + (k - 1) * (x - known_xmin_value)) ** 3, (k, 1, integer_unknown_limit))

f = lambdify([x, integer_unknown_limit], expr)
res = {}

# NOTE: this loop may take a few minutes, depending on the machine.
# I suggest to lower the upper limit
for ul in range(1, 1000):
    print(ul)
    try:
        r = root(f, 2, args=(ul,))
        if r.success:
            res[ul] = r.x[0]
    except:
        pass

plt.figure()
plt.plot(list(res.keys()), res.values())
plt.xlabel("u (upper limit)")
plt.ylabel("x where f(x)=0")
plt.title("f(x) = $%s$" % latex(expr))
plt.show()
```

As you can see, for each upper limit value in the considered subset, the expression is satisfied at some value of x.

[image]

EDIT: note that the same can be done with sympy's `nsolve`. Just replace the for loop with:

```py
for ul in range(1, 1000):
    print(ul)
    try:
        res[ul] = nsolve(expr.subs(integer_unknown_limit, ul), x, 1)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: The `1` in `nsolve` is the initial guess. To improve performance you could break the for loop when the first solution is found.